# Bluetooth: how to send large files

Tags: bluetooth

I need to make an Android application that sends large files (100-500 KB) over Bluetooth.

It is very important to preserve the integrity of the data, avoid any corruption of the files sent.

Please should I implement my own protocol?

Is there a suitable profile that I can use? (it seems profiles support is limited in Android...)

Any third party library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the profiles that are implemented.
OPP - Object Push Profile can send files, but this is often limited to V-cards and in some case images.
FTP - File Transfer Profile can send larger files.

There is no specific application needed, you should be able to do it from native android as long as both devices supports the profile in question.

For example, enter the gallery and choose to share an image over Bluetooth, then select the receiving party.

Or enter file manager and choose to share file over Bluetooth.

If you want to write your own program that sends files, you can find the specifications for the profiles and protocols on Bluetooth.org or developer information on Bluetooth.com

Comment: Neither of the profiles, AFAIK, are implemented in Android :-(((

Comment: Then you will have to implement it yourself, that should be interesting.
More at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html
and at Bluetooth.com


I would suggest looking in to the FTP profile

Comment: I Think OPP is implemented in latest, at leastI can see it on 5.1